# How to configure SSL for Meteor email sendMail?

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, meteor

My meteor app is running behind a firewall and my smtp settings for gmail are not getting through:

e.g. process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://user@gmail.com:password@smtp.googlemail.com:465"

I get 'Exception while invoking method 'sendEmail' Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH'

I gather I need to set SSL but don't know where/how to do this.

Any ideas?

many thanks

Max

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it correctly but the user:password part can't have an '@' symbol in it or the system gets confused.

This should do what you want:

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://user%40gmail.com:password@smtp.googlemail.com:465"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks -

FWIW, I wanted to use meteor to access a local mail server on my linux box. (My VPN won't let me access mailgun or any other remote mail server.)

This turned out to be pretty simple: process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://localhost:25"

Note, this is on a local mail server without authentication.

take care

Max